# Apache: Set index.html to raw text

Tags: apache, wget

I'm trying to get apache to server / as a raw text file instead of an html type file. I have exhausted everything I can think of like forced encoding, content-type, rewriterule removetype removehandler, addtype, addhandler, etc.

I'd like it to work exactly like this page:

```
wget -qO- https://setup.ius.io | sh
```

However, when I do it on my server, I get:

```
wget -qO- 'http://blah.com' | sh
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">'
```

Comment: But that `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">` **is** the first line of your index.html?

Comment: No, the first line is #!/bin/bash. It's just a plan text file, not html.

Comment: I really think you are then getting the content of some other file. If you remove ` | sh` you should see the whole content, perhaps that would help determine what is going on.

Comment: When I remove the | sh, I only get the actual file as expected. Not html at all. It has to be something Apache is doing.